# C# Get substring with specific pattern from string

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, substring

I have a list of strings like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Item 1: #item1#");
list.Add("Item 2: #item2#");
list.Add("Item 3: #item3#");
```

How can I get and add the substrings #item1#, #item2# etc into a new list?

I am only able to get the complete string if it contains a "#" by doing this:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if(item.Contains("#"))
    {
        //Add item to new list
    }
}
```

Comment: something with these functions: substring(FirstIndexOf('#'), LastIndexOf('#'));

Comment: What to return if the string does not contains the part `#item#`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could have a look at [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx). If you know a little bit about regular expressions (in your case it would be a quite simple pattern: `"#[^#]+#"`), you can use it to extract all items starting and ending with `'#'` with any number of other characters other than `'#'` in between.

Example:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("Item 3: #item3#", "#[^#]+#");
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Captures[0].Value); // Will output "#item3#"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using a regex with LINQ. (Not sure your exact requirements reference the regex, so now you may have two problems.)

```
var list = new List<string> ()
{
    "Item 1: #item1#",
    "Item 2: #item2#",
    "Item 3: #item3#",
    "Item 4: #item4#",
    "Item 5: #item5#",
};

var pattern = @"#[A-za-z0-9]*#";

list.Select (x => Regex.Match (x, pattern))
    .Where (x => x.Success)
    .Select (x => x.Value)
    .ToList ()
    .ForEach (Console.WriteLine);
```

Output:

> #item1#
>
> #item2#
>
> #item3#
>
> #item4#
>
> #item5#

Answer (score 2):

LINQ would do the job nicely:

```
var newList = list.Select(s => '#' + s.Split('#')[1] + '#').ToList();
```

Or if you prefer query expressions:

```
var newList = (from s in list
               select '#' + s.Split('#')[1] + '#').ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions as suggested with Botz3000 and combine those with LINQ:

```
var newList = new List(
    from match in list.Select(s => Regex.Match(s, "#[^#]+#"))
    where match.Success
    select match.Captures[0].Value
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will solve your problem.
But if the string **does not contain** `#item#` then the original string will be used.

```
var inputList = new List<string>
    {
        "Item 1: #item1#",
        "Item 2: #item2#",
        "Item 3: #item3#",
        "Item 4: item4"
    };

var outputList = inputList
    .Select(item =>
        {
            int startPos = item.IndexOf('#');
            if (startPos < 0)
                return item;

            int endPos = item.IndexOf('#', startPos + 1);
            if (endPos < 0)
                return item;
            return item.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos + 1);
        })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
List<string> substring_list = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in list)
{
    int first = item.IndexOf("#");
    int second = item.IndexOf("#", first);
    substring_list.Add(item.Substring(first, second - first);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by simply using:

```
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    list.ForEach(x => list2.Add(x.Substring(x.IndexOf("#"), x.Length - x.IndexOf("#"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var itemList = new List<string>();
foreach(var text in list){
string item = text.Split(':')[1];
itemList.Add(item);


}
```